# How can I use regex (based on values in a list) to extract values in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame *pd*.

| Product | Sales | Receipts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paint | 1000 | 400 |
| Black paint | 2000 | 300 |
| White piant | 3000 | 200 |
| Orange pint | 4000 | 100 |
| Red wallpaper | 4000 | 100 |
| Green wall | 4000 | 100 |

This is my code

```
list = ["paint", "pint", "piant"]
rgx_pd = re.compile ('|'.join(list))
```

How can I use the values in the list to create a new dataframe based on *pd*, but one with all products matching the values (*pdt*) in the list and one without (*pdf*)?

Comment: df_1 = df[df["Porudct"].isin(your_list)]
df_2 = df[~df["Porudct"].isin(your_list)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method.

Considering that your dataframe is named as `pd` like you said in the question:

```
pd[pd.Product.str.contains(rgx_pd, case=False, regex=True)]
```

The problem is that you can't use a compiled regex expression with this method, so you're going need to change this line:

```
rgx_pd = re.compile('|'.join(list))
```

With:

```
rgx_pd = r'|'.join(list)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me out. Based in your feedback, I tried the following:

    rgx_so = r'|'.join(list)

This immediately gives me the error below. What am I doing wrong? 

    TypeError: can only join an iterable.

Comment: You problably messed with the name of the variables. Try changing the name of your dataframe for something diferent thant "pd" (that is a alias for "pandas" when importing) and change the name of your list that contains the words you are trying to match on regex (because the name "list" is a reserved word of python). Without looking exactly what you're doing in your code is hard to say what's wrong. But the error is saying that the variable you're putting inside the join function is not a list (or an iterable type).